# How to get a list of user's friends via facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

Say I was to let a user login to my website using facebook, by something like the following url:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=$appId&
redirect_uri=$return&scope=user_birthday,email,user_location
```

Would there be a way for me to get a list of all the user's friends and display pictures (where available)? Which graph API function could I use to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to perform a query to the `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends`

Sample is here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

And as soon as you have user id - you can point your `<img src="" />` to the `http://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/picture` url.

Comment: @pal4life: `access_token` identifies user. So what do you think about `/me` without `access_token`? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set up an app with Facebook, as you will need an API key to do most of this using the official Facebook apis. [Here](http://www.joeyrivera.com/2010/facebook-graph-api-app-easy-w-php-sdk/) is a great reference if you still need to do that, from Joey Rivera. Just follow the first part to set up an app and get all hooked up.

The API function would be `FB.api("/me/friends")` [(Source)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/). It returns an array of JSON Objects, with each friends Facebook ID and Name. If you want to get the pictures, you would need to query each friend in the list for the equivalent of `FB.api("/me/picture/"`. You could do this with FQL, embedded in a for statement over the list of friends. Or, a similar method with a simple api call to `[Friend Facebook id]/picture` would give it to you if it was publicly available.

You may still need to ask for the picture file explicitly, as it will only give you the file name.

This assumes a Javascript implementation of your app.

Answer (score 1):

After a proper facebook authentication for a user to login.....

you could access his friends list using the fql query....

the following worked fine for me....

```
<?php
    try
    {
        $fql    =   "SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid = me()
                     OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";
        $param  =   array(
            'method'    => 'fql.query',
            'query'     => $fql,
            'callback'  => ''
        );
        $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);

    }
    catch(Exception $o)
    {
        d($o);
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/picture
```

eg:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture
```

This will display marks photo