# How many friends on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a list of user's friends via facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387121/how-to-get-a-list-of-users-friends-via-facebook)

I have a Facebook App and I want to know how many friends a user has. When the user login on my web through Facebook API, I setup the permissions:

```
header('Location: ' . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'email, user_birthday, user_location')));
```

But dunno how to ask Facebook API about the friends that a user has. Im wondering your email with this code:

```
    if($facebook->api(array('method'=>'users.hasAppPermission', 'ext_perm'=>'email')))
    {
        $myarr = array('method'=>'users.getInfo', 'fields'=>'email', 'uids'=>$uid);
        $emailarr = $facebook->api($myarr);
    }
```

Anyone knows the permission and the API method to request that info?. Thanks in advance!.

[SOLVED] With [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387121/how-to-get-a-list-of-users-friends-via-facebook). The API call:

```
    $me2 = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
    $num_amigos = count($me2['data']);
    $me['friends']=$num_amigos;
```

Thanks for your comments!.

Comment: please go through http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+many+friends+on+Facebook+[php] to see if any of them solve your question. If not, update your question to point out why. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review the [rules on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).  In particular, changing the title of your question is not the correct way to mark it as resolved.  If none of the existing answers resolved your issue, you should create an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this url:
`https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>`

Check this too: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the php-sdk @ github : https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/